# How to get the each coordinate with click event when using drawing library

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the coordinates when each time I click to a point when I drawing the polygon.
I know there is a method that used to get the coordinates of the points after the polygon drawn but that not what I looking for.

I'm looking for something when I execute the drawing Polygon event, each time I select the point I able to get the coordinates instantly when the drawing Polygon event is running.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', OverlayCompleteEvent => {
    const polygonPoints = OverlayCompleteEvent.overlay.getPath().getArray();
    
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'click', function(){
     // get the points here...
    });

  
  });
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `fromPointToLatLng()` method? For more infos look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/image-overlay#Projection

Comment: It doesn't not work since I m running drawing library in the meantime. If I using the drawing manager, the library will disable the map to use the click event.